# How to enforce client to use SSL for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

Environment:

```
Windows 10, localhost, same machine
pg 12
node 14
openssl 1.1.1k
```

I've read and done pg docs starting from [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ssl-tcp.html).

**postgresql.conf** (in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data, my understanding is it controls pg DB server)

```
ssl = on # per pg doc: server will listen for both normal and SSL connections on the same TCP port, and will negotiate with any connecting client on whether to use SSL
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' 
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt' # per pg doc, 18.9.3: To require the client to supply a trusted certificate
ssl_crl_file = ''
```

**pg_hba.conf** (in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data, my understanding is its effect is on client such as web API or any DB consumers, not DB server)

```
...
hostssl all             all             127.0.0.1/32 cert clientcert=1
...
```

pSQL shows it's communicating over SSL:
[image]

But a simple node project can connect **without SSL**:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './environment/PostgreSql.env'});

const pgp = require('pg-promise')();    

const db = pgp(
    {
        user: process.env.PGuser,
        host: process.env.PGhost,
        database: process.env.PGdatabase,
        password: process.env.PGpassword,
        port: process.env.PGport,
        
        ssl: false  // optional, but true gets code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
    }
);

var sql = 'select * from current.testssl()';  
db.any(sql)
    .then
    (
        good => 
        { 
            console.log(good); // ssl false gets data 
        },
        bad => 
        { 
            console.log(bad); 
/* ssl true gets 
at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17) 
{
code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE', 
stack: 'Error: unable to verify the first certificate…ckTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)', 
message: 'unable to verify the first certificate'
}
*/
            
        }
    );
```

**Final Solution** based on @Lauranz Albe's and @jjanes, pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
hostnossl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  reject  # must be the 1st line!
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0   cert clientcert=verify-full
```

Comment: The problem is in something you are not showing us.  What is in your .env file?  What are the rest of the lines of your pg_hba.conf *in order*?

Comment: @jjanes `.env` contains things shown in my code above: `user, host, databasename, password`, etc. Please complete content of **pg_hba.conf** above.

Comment: Reject has to be the first line, not the last.  But what is the host?  It matters what it actually is (well, with that pg_hba it doesn't maybe, but in general.  127.0.0.1 is different from 192.168.0.37)

Comment: @jjanes Host? localhost. It works for the node project. pgAdmin is still able to connect without http**S** on `http://127.0.0.1:53819/browser/`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line at the beginning of your `pg_hba.conf`:

```
hostnossl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  reject
```

Then you have to reload PostgreSQL (check the log file if the reload caused any errors).

That will reject all connection attempts that use an unencrypted TCP connection.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for details.

Comment: still the same, also tried `hostnossl  all  all  127.0.0.1/32  reject` with machine restarted. Is it because I'm on the same machine?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to reload PostgreSQL. If that still does not work, you are editing the wrong `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: You're right to reload. After each edit, I "shut down" the machine for at least 10 seconds before turning back on. Tested `hostnossl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  reject` and `hostnossl  all  all  127.0.0.1/32  reject`. There is only one `pg_hba.conf` in my machine, located at `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data` (the data directory of pg). I also tested by adding some extra, got `LOG F0000 authentication option not in name=value format: md5 
FATAL XX000 could not load pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Then you don't have the entries in the correct order.